# How to multiselect values in listbox into template filed asp. net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to multiselect values in listbox into template field, when it is in edit mode. Is there a way to do it?
I tried something like this. I add HiddenField to bind there a values and then w JS code I want to select selected values (I can do it but I dont have a `class` in `HiddenField` so it isn't a good solution).

Also I don't know is there a chance to do it by server side becasue it didn't recognize Id's of mine Listbox

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Conditions" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdn_dd_conditions" class="bottom" Value='<%# Bind("conditions") %>' />
        <asp:ListBox ID="dd_conditions" runat="server" CssClass="conditions" SelectionMode="Multiple" multiple="multiple">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Value1" Text="Text2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Value2" Text="Text2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="Others" Text="Others"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("conditions") %>' Font-Size="10px"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you want to get the values which were selected in the listbox, when the page posts back? Or something else? It's not actually very clear what you want. Can you explain better?

Comment: I want to bind from server the values to listbox.

Comment: And what is the data source? Listboxes can be databound quite easily. If it's part of a Repeater you probably want to do it from the ItemDataBound event of the repeater

Comment: `List<object> list` is data source. Then I just `GV.DataSource = list` and `GV.DataBind();` But I want to bind which ones are selected.

Comment: So I guess you have some other data which describes which ones are selected?

Comment: This one `<%# Bind("conditions") %>` delimited with coma are selected

Comment: Well in code-behind you have to loop through the items, find the related item in the list and set them selected. But why do you have a comma-separated list like that? Please tell me that's not how you store it in your database?

Comment: Ok I will try like you said. I store data like this x)

Comment: Then I would suggest your database is de-normalised and potentially hard to query, and needs a more correct design.

Comment: I have no influence on it. Thanks

Comment: Ok well it doesn't matter directly for this question, but you could mention it to those who do have influence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the ListBox in the RowDataBound event of the GridView

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow and in edit mode
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && (e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //use findcontrol to locate the listbox and cast it
        ListBox lb = e.Row.FindControl("dd_conditions") as ListBox;

        //loop all the items in a listbox
        for (int i = 0; i < lb.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            //check the values and set the Selected property
            if (lb.Items[i].Value == row["conditions"].ToString())
            {
                lb.Items[i].Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```