# How to load Drop down list values from database while Row Editing in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I tried the following way, the data set is coming and table is binding.
But data is not inserting to the assigned drop down list in the gridview while Row Editing event

```
  protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    int index = e.NewEditIndex;
  DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)GridView2.Rows[index].FindControl("Receipttypeddl");
    if (ddl != null)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da;

        con.Open();
        string qry;
        qry = "select * from ReceiptType";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry);
        cmd.Connection = con;

        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(ds);
        con.Close();
        ddl.DataSource = ds;
        ddl.DataTextField = "Receiptmode";
        ddl.DataValueField = "Receiptmode";
        ddl.DataBind(); 
        ListItem i = new ListItem("", "");//Data is not inserting into ddl
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, i);

    }

    DataTable dts = new DataTable();
    dts = (DataTable)ViewState["Receiptdetails"];
    GridView2.DataSource = dts;
    GridView2.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Bind `DropdownList` in `GridView_ItemDataBound` handler `if(e.Item.ItemType == EditItem)...` Or better use `asp:ListView` control which is much more flexible then rather old `GridView`.

Comment: There is no `item_data_bound` in `Gridview` , you mean to say `Row_Data_Bound`  ??

Comment: Yes, I mean `GridView_RowDataBound` event / handler.

Comment: See my answer here. Just replace ListBox with DropDownList. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516872/how-to-multiselect-values-in-listbox-into-template-filed-asp-net

Comment: @AlexKudryashev thanks man .. i have completed it that minute itself

Answer (score 0):

you need bind dropdown on RowDataBound.

there seems to be no need to go to dB for each item.

```
    protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView2.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindGridView();
    }

    private void BindGridView()
    {
        DataTable dts = new DataTable();
        dts = (DataTable)ViewState["Receiptdetails"];
        GridView2.DataSource = dts;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Receipttypeddl");
            BindDropdown(ddl);
        }
    }

    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
    private void BindDropdown(DropDownList ddl)
    {
        if (ds.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da;
            con.Open();
            string qry;
            qry = "select * from ReceiptType";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry);
            cmd.Connection = con;

            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
        }

        ddl.DataSource = ds;
        ddl.DataTextField = "Receiptmode";
        ddl.DataValueField = "Receiptmode";
        ddl.DataBind();
        ListItem i = new ListItem("", "");//Data is not inserting into ddl
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, i);
    }
```

Comment: @ levent i completed it...thanks for your time for posting